# String includes substrings from arrays

Tags: ruby

I have the following:

```
input string = "1234"
output new_array should = [12, 3, 4, 34]
```

Comment: post same input and output so that the question would be more clear

Comment: What is the empty regex doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def string_to_array(string)
  noun = ["d", "fgh", "i", "jk", "bcd", "cdef"]
  verb = ["cd", "ef", "f", "jkl", "abc"]

  ary = (noun+verb).select { |s| string.include? s }
  ary.unshift(ary.delete(string)).compact
end

string = "cdef"

string_to_array(string) #=> ["cdef", "d", "cd", "ef", "f"]
```

I used [`Array#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-select), [`Array#+`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-2B), [`Array#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-delete), [`Array#unshift`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-unshift), [`Array#compact`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-compact) and [`String#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-include-3F).

If you want to remove duplicate from output array, use [`Array#uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq)

Comment: Wow that was much more efficient than I was thinking, I will have to look up your references.  Thanks so much!

Comment: It seemed to fail one of my tests, the order came out incorrectly as "cd" should be second in the array.  As in the order should be ["cdef", "cd", "d", "ef", "f"] . Top priority in the ordering given to the order they appear in the string first, then by noun, then verb

Comment: @Sachin, yes, that's the difference. I've edited my answer for this condition.

Comment: I attempted this by making the string = "jklfgh", and the desired output would've been: ["jk", "jkl", "fgh", "f"] but received: ["fgh", "jk", "f", "jkl"]

Comment: Noun first, then verb as you describe.

Comment: Sorry I may not being clear, order of appearance in string is top priority, then noun, then verb.  Is there a way to sort the new array by an index of the string characters?

Comment: It occurs to me to apply `sort` and `match`

Comment: That last hint helped!  I figured it out.  It works with:  ary.sort_by&string.method(:index) .  Since you solved most of this I did not feel comfortable updating as if I answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-scan) (see the last sentence of the doc especially) together with a regular expression. My objective is to demonstrate this approach, not to suggest that it should be the preferred approach.

```
nouns = ["cdef", "d", "fgh", "i", "jk", "bcd"]
verbs = ["cd", "ef", "f", "jkl", "abc"]

R = Regexp.new (nouns+verbs).map { |s| "(?=(#{s}))?" }.join
  #=> /(?=(cdef))?(?=(d))?(?=(fgh))?(?=(i))?(?=(jk))?(?=(bcd))?(?=(cd))?(?=(ef))?(?=(f))?(?=(jkl))?(?=(abc))?/
```

```
def string_to_array(str, nouns, strings)
  str.scan(R).flatten.compact
end

str = "cdef"

string_to_array(str, nouns, verbs)
  #=> ["cdef", "cd", "d", "ef", "f"]
```

Note:

```
str.scan(R)
  #=> [["cdef", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "cd", nil, nil, nil, nil],
  #    [nil, "d", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
  #    [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "ef", nil, nil, nil],
  #    [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "f", nil, nil],
  #    [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]]
```

`(?=(cdef))?` (`(?=(cdef)?)` also works) is a positive lookahead enclosed in a capture group. It requires that a particular location in the string is immediately followed by the content of the lookahead, but is not part of the match itself. The question mark makes the lookahead optional.